# View User Login History with WindowsLogon [Powershell]

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to figure out how to view a users login history to a specific machine. This command is meant to be ran locally to view how long consultant spends logged into a server.

I currently only have knowledge to this command that pulls the full EventLog but I need to filter it so it can display per-user or a specific user.

> Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-WinLogon -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-5) -ComputerName $env:computername

Comment: Look for event IDs 4634: An account was logged off and 4624: An account was successfully logged on.

Comment: I lack so much experience with powershell. How would I go about this?

Comment: No idea. You will need to wait for a PowerShell guru to come along ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off of the discussion in the comments, you can search the Event Log using Powershell.

```
Get-EventLog security | Where-Object {$_.TimeGenerated -gt '9/15/16'} | Where-Object {($_.InstanceID -eq 4634) -or ($_.InstanceID -eq 4624)} | Select-Object Index,TimeGenerated,InstanceID,Message
```

- `Get-EventLog` allows you to access the Event Log, specifically the Security logs
- The first `Where-Object` specifies that you want any records that are newer than the provided date
- The second `Where-Object` specifies the two Event IDs you're interested in
- `Select-Object` lets us only return columns we're interested having in the output

You will likely need to run this from an elevated instance of Powershell since this is accessing the Windows registry.

Comment: Nice! Only problem is that after running this script in elevated PS nothing is printed in the prompt.

Comment: In the Event Log under Security, are there any events that actually match this criteria (Event ID in 4634/4624 and date>=Sep 15th)?

Comment: Probably not. Would I have to enable logging for Security?

Comment: No, unless you've disabled the Windows Event Log service.

Comment: I see. I am looking at my event logs but it is strange how that command does not work, I do have Security logs for that day and am also running PS as Admin.

Comment: Sorry about that, looks like I had to play around with the Event IDs. Thank you so much again Root!